# GCP and AWS pricing - Are these important to know?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm a newbie on cloud. I've been reading through AWS and GCP's billing/pricing documentation and I find the pricing on transfer, retrieval between and within regions, the requests....etc  extremely confusing for me to understand and remember.

Does knowing and remembering the pricing make a significant difference in cloud deployment? What is the best way to go about understanding and remembering the prices?

Comment: AWS, Google, Azure, etc have free courses and videos on understanding billing. Yes, these are very important to learn. Sign up with AWS Training and watch the free courses: https://aws.amazon.com/training/ Another great resource is YouTube. I created a Video Lab series on Google Cloud Billing: https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/ An example for Azure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxtBdjfWCZU

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud pricing is an ever changing operation so trying to remember the exact pricing of usage is not important as even if you can remember it, it might not be accurate. Cloud providers make announcements daily so these figures can always change.Instead trying to remember a banding for pricing i.e. low, medium, high as this is more likely to be the kind of knowledge you would draw upon in an initial plan.

Pricing can be be very confusing so you're not alone in this, you will never remember all of the pricing concepts for every service however having an understanding roughly of traffic to the internet, traffic within regions and traffic with availability zones generally will apply the same way across services (at least in AWS).

If you're trying to price a service in AWS there are specific pricing pages for each service with examples of all of the calculations. There is also a [pricing estimator tool](https://calculator.aws/#/). If you're ever unsure overestimate rather than underestimate. Google Cloud also has a [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).